# single page view PDF-renderer java swing

Tags: java, swing, pdfrenderer

as the title says.

How can I display all pdf pages in a single panel? Like the single page view of adobe pdf reader.

I'm using `pdf-renderer-1.0.5.jar`

Comment: Is this SwingLabs PDFRenderer?  What does the docs say? Have your checked Google and the projects home page?

Comment: I haven't read O: I was just reading the sample code and understand it.. I'll see the docs.

Comment: can't find docs. anyways, is there any way I can display all of the pages of a single PDF, single page view, without any controls in a swing panel. Only the panel and a scrollpane?

Comment: From what project does `pdf-render` come from.  I can 3 on the first page of Google alone :P

Comment: I'm querying the wrong input! AHAH

Comment: Still can't find answers..

Comment: Who wrote the library?

Comment: I think it's Sun? found this on the manifest.mf `Created-By: 11.0-b11 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
Main-Class: com.sun.pdfview.PDFViewer`

I got it from here [link](http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.swinglabs/pdf-renderer/1.0.5)

Comment: Start by taking a look at [this](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-06-2008/jw-06-opensourcejava-pdf-renderer.html). I've only skimmed it, but it might give you a start. When my 10 month old wakes up (off my lap) I will have a closer look

Comment: Okay. I'll look into it later. I'm going to rest for now. I've been working for 10hours straight xD

Comment: I still can't find one.. :/

Comment: [this](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-06-2008/jw-06-opensourcejava-pdf-renderer.html?page=4) demonstrates a possible solution, it renders a single page, but you should be able to play around with it

Comment: I was able to render single pages, using some next and previous buttons. I was trying to set 2 pagePanels, but it doesn't seem to work..

Answer (score 0):

Using the `pdf-render` project, you can get a `PDFPage` for each page in the PDF, render each to an `java.awt.Image` and display the collection of Images, e.g. in a `GridView`.